# Run javascript onsubmit before browser checks form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with a billing-address and a shipping-address.
These addresses have some fields with the "required" attribute.

If a checkbox "use billing as shipping" is checked, the billing adress should be copied to shipping onSubmit.

But when I click submit, at least chrome does its checks and complain about a field being empty, and halts the submitting before my copy_billing_to_shipping can run.

Is there a "hook" on submit which runs before browser validates?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your submit button by a simple button, like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myOwnValidate(this)" />
```

and then, if everything is ok in your validate method, submit the form:

```
myOwnValidate = function(input) {
 ...
 if(valid) {
   input.form.submit();
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Some folks like to add a "click" handler to buttons on the form to trigger validation. This is not ideal because users can submit forms by pressing the enter key when focused in a text input. This would bypass form validation.

The better way to do this is to add an event listener for the "submit" event on the form. Your event handler function should return true or false. If true, the form will be submitted.

Just be sure not to have any javascript bugs in your event handler, because if you do, the form will be submitted anyways.

```
<form id="myform">
  ....
</form>

<script>
  function validate(e) {
    var isValid = ...; // Some logic to determine validity.
    return isValid;
  }

  document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", validate);
</script>
```

Comment: You failed to see the problem. My onsubmit would copy some text from billing-address to shipping-address, but the browser inbuild validation finds the empty shipping address, and prevents the my onsubmit to run.